# getting data from different columns goes wrong

Tags: python

I made a code to check if the number in the header "Code to compare" is the the same or not. If it is the same, it should get the date in the index, remove the date in its own row and put that information in a new column with the header "Date to compare", but it takes all the dates and doesn't filter.

Can you guys help?

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    code_to_compare = row["Code to compare"]
    matching_dates = df[df["Code to compare"] == code_to_compare].index.to_list()
    matching_dates.remove(index)  # Verwijder de huidige datum uit de lijst
    matching_dates_str = ", ".join(str(date) for date in matching_dates)
    df.at[index, "Date to compare"] = matching_dates_str
```

I tried multiple things. The same code works in a different script, just not in the one im currently working on .

Comment: can you tell us more about the structure of dataframe.

Comment: I recommend using group by "Code to compare" column and then apply a lambda function that compute the ", ".join(str(date) for date in matching_dates), for me this is the best and the fastest approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are running over the rows in your dataframe and then compare each row to all rows again. Please add a print statement to your code after the definition of matching_dates. Then you will see What your are “matching”.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide structure of df, can assume better.
I assume that the date column in your dataframe is named `"Date"`. If it has a different name, please replace `"Date"` with the correct `column name.`
By using `df.at[date_index, "Date"]`, we can access the actual date value from the df instead of just the index, you can use `print` there to check correct `values`

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    code_to_compare = row["Code to compare"]
    matching_dates = df[df["Code to compare"] == code_to_compare].index.to_list()
    matching_dates.remove(index)  # Remove the current index from the list
    matching_dates_str = ", ".join(str(df.at[date_index, "Date"]) for date_index in matching_dates)
    df.at[index, "Date to compare"] = matching_dates_str
```

Comment: the date is actually the index, that is how the data is gathered from the platform. So it can not find "Date" as it doesn't exist even if i give it that as header. Index works, it gives the dates, but the code doesn't check with the "code to compare".

What i need is:
2023-01-01, 123, 2023-01-04   (for example)
2023-01-02, 124, 
2023-01-03, 125,
2023-01-04, 123, 2023-01-01

What i get:
2023-01-01, 123, 2023-01-02, 2023-01-03, 2023-01-04